# How do you remove a QPalette from a QWidget

Tags: qt, qpalette

According to [Qt's QWidget documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html):

> QWidget propagates explicit palette roles from parent to child. If you assign a brush or color to a specific role on a palette and assign that palette to a widget, that role will propagate to all the widget's children, overriding any system defaults for that role.

I have a widget hierarchy:

```
QMainWindow 'window'
     |_QGroupBox 'box'
          |_QLabel 'label'
          |_QLabel 'label2'
```

So if I were to call `box->setPalette(somePalette)` the new palette is used to paint `box`, `label` and `label2`

Now I want to undo this, i.e. I want `box`, `label` and `label2` to use my default palette, which is easy, I call `box->setPalette(window->palette())` right?

The issue with this is `box` still technically has a custom palette set (it makes a deep copy of the palette you pass it), if I modify the palette of `window` it no longer propagates through `box` to `label` and `label2`.

So, how do I actually remove the palette from `box` so that palette propogation is restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I actually remove the palette from box so that palette propagation is restored?

You can use [QWidget::setAttribute](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute) to explicitly set or remove  `Qt::WA_WindowPropagation` flag to make sure the palette is propagated (or not). From my experience that sometimes require `QWidget::update()` to be called afterwards.

UPDATE: There is also `Qt::WA_SetPalette` attribute for enabling/disabling individual widget palette update. With this specific case we need to propagate the palette down to the nested widgets first as the author suggested in comments e.g. `box->setPalette(window->palette()); box->setAttribute(WA_SetPalette, false);`.

Comment: The docs say `Makes a toplevel window inherit font and palette from its parent.` `box` isn't a top level window...

Comment: Found a `WA_SetPalette` widget attribute, going to try that (`Indicates that the widget has a palette of its own.`)

Comment: I can confirm that `WA_SetPalette` must be set to false but only after setting the palette to exactly match the parent's palette. `box->setPalette(window->palette()); box->setAttribute(WA_SetPalette, false);` No `update` necessary!

Comment: See @Troyseph, with all complications e.g. stylesheet and overaloaded paintEvent sometimes it misbehaves and that is why `update()` may come handy. I guess the answer needs some polish with your feedback added. I will wait for a couple of hours then.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but all you need to do to unset a palette is pass a default constructed QPalette like this: `myWidget->setPalette(QPalette())`

When you do this the `setPalette` function will handle the `WA_SetPalette` attribute for you and whatever other internal machinery is needed to get things working.

I've tested this in Qt6.5 but I think it should work in older versions as well.

Comment: Nice, so in my example, setting this on `box` would propogate the `WA_SetPalette` attribute down to the child nodes, and subsequent changes in palette to `window` (the parent of `box`) would apply to the child palettes as well?

Comment: @Troyseph, I believe that is how it would work but I haven't tested that particular case. In my case I just had a widget with no children that I wanted to remove a custom palette from.